# In MySQL , how do I change the maximum number of concurrent connections?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm editing my.cfg right now and I want to change the max # of connections.

Answer (score 3):

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
max_connections = 250
```

Open your MySQL configuration file in your favorite text editor and set the variable "max_connections" to the value you need. Once that's done, restart your MySQL daemon with /etc/init.d/mysqld restart (the init script path may differ on your system).

Comment: after that you can verify with query show variables like '%max_connections%';